# Log file is not created from the service

Tags: linux, unix, daemon

On my Linux box I run this command to start my tomcat.

```
service tomcat-test start
```

After that I call my webservice and look for a log file named `jdbc.log`. And it is nowhere there.

But if I take the tomcat run command from (`ps ax| grep tomcat`) and run at console, then I find my `jdbc.log` file on current directory (from where I ran it).

The command is a simple tomcat run command with java then few switches. Any idea at where the file has created? I mean what is the path or home for the linux `service`. I tried at `/var/log` but no luck.

Comment: Edit `/etc/init.d/tomcat` to add `echo $PWD > /tmp/tomcat.txt` just before it runs the tomcat command.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to look the whole server for it:

```
find / -name jdbc.log
```

Then to get only `*log` files modified lately:

```
find / -mtime -1 -name *log
```